# Initializing/Assigning class member variables to other class member variables

Tags: php

I'm getting back into web dev and re-learning PHP the right way, and I'm having an extremely stupid issue that I should be able to solve but cant..

I'm trying to basically assign a base url value as a class property, and then use that value to assign to a new class property..

```
class Endpoints {

   protected $baseURL = 'https://api.com';
   protected $baseAccountsURL = $this->baseURL . '/accounts';

}
```

I tried accessing $baseURL directly, without $this->, but it fails as well. I'd prefer to use CONSTs, but the ability to assign CONSTs to other CONSTs won't be available until 5.6.  I've reviewed the [PHP Class Properties](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) page, and searched SO, but I come from a Java background so my issue here is probably terminology.. and syntax :p

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assign properties that way, you will need to do it in the constructor:

```
class Endpoints {

   protected $baseURL = 'https://api.com';
   protected $baseAccountsURL;

   public function __construct()
   {
       $this->baseAccountsURL = $this->baseURL . '/accounts';
   }
}
```

Alternatively, this would work:

```
class Endpoints {

   protected $baseURL = 'https://api.com';
   protected $baseAccountsURL = 'https://api.com/accounts';

}
```

But I think the first option is what you need.